# Azure: What is an "Affinity Group"?

Tags: azure

MongoDB docs state to set up an [affinity group](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux-in-azure/). What is an affinity group in the context of Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group of resources that are affinitized to each other. That is, resources that you would like to be "close" to each other as an optimization.

MongoDB might want an affinity group so that mongo db resources will be able to communicate with each other more efficiently.